# My script doesnt work when I change the object property from "LastWriteTime" to "CreationTime", it just deletes everything?

Tags: powershell, automation

Ive been running around like crazy lately with this script that Im trying to modify it to suit my needs. I recently found out that deleting the files using "LastWriteTime" is not what Im after..

What I need my script to do is to delete the files that are older than 30 days using the "CreationTime" property, the problem is that after I modify the script to use this it deletes the entire folder structure?

How can this small modification change the behavior of the entire script?

This is what Im using:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$del30 = "D:\CompanyX_ftp\users"

$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"

Get-ChildItem $del30 -Recurse | 

Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |

Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |

Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch | 

Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |

Remove-Item -Recurse
```

So if I were to replace the "CreationTime" property with "LastWriteTime" the script will run and do what its supposed to but if I use "CreationTime" it just deletes everything under the folder structure including the folders themselves and the paths that its supposed to ignore.

**UPDATE**: The script is working for me now for the actual deletion of the files but for the script that Im using to just get a **report** on the actual files that the script will delete is actually including the paths of the ignorelist.txt file?
Please see below script:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$del30 = "D:\CompanyX_ftp\users"

#Specify path for ignore-list

$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"

Get-ChildItem $del5 -File -Recurse | 

Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |

Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |

Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch | 

Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,CreationTime
```

**ignorelist.txt** sample data:

D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerA\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerB\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerC\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerD\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerE\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerF\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerG\Customer Downloads
D:\CompanyX_ftp\users\ftp-customerH\Customer Downloads\

Any ideas on why its including the paths that I have mentioned on the ignorelist.txt? (I will also provide an image for better illustration).

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance with this.

//Lennart

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $del30 -File -Recurse` should do the trick. You are currently enumerating directories as well.

Comment: Hey! That did the trick and its actually respecting the ignorelist.txt exclusions but when I ran the other version of the script which is only supposed to check the files that it will delete without actually taking any action is actually including the paths that I have listed on the ignorelist.txt file.

Comment: You have to iterate through the file. In other words, you're just passing it a list as a list. `Foreach` loop can help you accomplish this by iterating (going through each line in the file) through the list, and doing it one by one, instead of all of them at a time.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: Im sry but Im barely entering the powershell scripting world and do not understand your reply, what I want to accomplish with my RemoveFilesOlderThanCheck script is **just to get a report** on the files that the script will eventually delete.

This is just a routine check to see the files that the script will delete before we actually run a modified version of the script that will actually delete the files.

Comment: Use `-Exclude` parameter.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala In replacement for this line?

$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"

Comment: How does the content of "ignorelist.txt" look like? Please add some sample data.

Comment: hmm, maybe im looking at this wrong. Let me look at this when i get to work. Whats inside your `$ignore` list

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I updated my post with sample data on what the ignorelist.txt file contains.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your code. If I understand it correctly, the first `Get-ChildItem` is supposed to return only directories, which will be filtered by `$ignore`. Of these directories you want to list files that have a creation time less than `$limit`. Is this correct?

Comment: @zett42 So I basically what Im doing is that I want to use one script to *only* provide me a report of the files that are older than 30 days based on the "CreationTime" file property. The second script that I will use will actually execute the deletion of these files.

Comment: @zett42 And by the way, your first reply solved the problem for my script that deletes the files but I still need to get the one that gives me the report and the problem right now is that its returning me results that are including paths that are contained in my ignorelist.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with the updated code:

- Duplicate recursion. First `Get-ChildItem` iterates over contents of directory recursively. Later in the pipeline another recursive iteration starts on items returned by the first `Get-ChildItem`, causing overlap.
- When filtering by `$ignore`, only paths that exactly match against the `$ignore` paths are being ignored. Paths that are children of items in the ignore list are not ignored.

Here is how I would do this. Create a function `Test-IgnoreFile` that matches given path against an ignore list, checking if the current path starts with any path in the ignore list. This way child paths are ignored too. This enables us to greatly simplify the pipeline.

```
Param(
    [switch] $ReportOnly
)

# Returns $true if $File.Fullname starts with any path in $Ignore (case-insensitive)
Function Test-IgnoreFile( $File, $Ignore ) {
    foreach( $i in $Ignore ) { 
        if( $File.FullName.StartsWith( $i, [StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) { 
            return $true
        }
    }
    $false
}

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$del30 = "D:\CompanyX_ftp\users"

$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"

Get-ChildItem $del30 -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit -and -not ( Test-IgnoreFile $_ $ignore ) } |
    ForEach-Object {
        if( $ReportOnly) {
            $_ | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime
        }
        else {
            $_ | Remove-Item -Force
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the thing is that I already have a script that does the deletion part and that I believe is working fine and in order to trust the script I just need to be able to slightly modify it so that we can trust what the actual deletion script will do. Makes sense??

Comment: I cannot have completely different code on the scripts because what Im looking for is to be able to trust what the code is doing (Sry, Im just trying to be as clear as possible).

Comment: your suggestions is working fine to get the report, what Im trying to do now is to modify it to actually delete the files... again so that I can have one for running the report and one for deletion.

Comment: @LennartHallden I've added a switch parameter `ReportOnly` to the script so you don't need two different scripts. If the switch is passed, there will be only reporting. If the switch is not passed, files will be deleted. You can call the script like `& .\NameOfTheScript.ps1 -ReportOnly`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I think this is exactly what I needed, tomorrow I have a final test with this. Thanks for all help so far Zett42!!!

Comment: Now Im trying to get the output of the script to be attached on an email and sent out to a list of recipients. Im trying to make it work with "Send-MailMessage" but its not working, what can I read to understand how to accomplish this?